# Trying to add a live website URL in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, url, react-redux, routes, react-router

I am trying to add the live website URL i.e "https://covid19statswebsite.netlify.app/" so that when I click on my Button it should redirect me to the above URL. How can I do that?
Any Suggestions?

below is my Button,

```
import React from "react";
import "./Banner.css"
import BannerVideo from './videos/video-2.mp4'
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
// import axios from './axios'
// import requests from "./Request";

function Banner(){
    const history = useHistory()
    return(
           <div className="banner-container">
            <video src={BannerVideo} autoPlay loop muted/>
            <h1>ADVENTURE AWAITS</h1>
            <p>What are you waiting for?</p>



/////////// Button That needs to redirect it ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            <div className="banner-buttons">
                <br/><br/><Button onClick={() => history.push("/covid")} className="covid"><span>COVID-19 Status</span></Button>
            </div>

        </div>

    );

}

export default Banner
```

This is my **App.js** file which imports the **Banner.js** file above for Routes. I am not sure that the thing I want will happen with Routes or not. So I'd really love to know any other alternative if present.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/ProfileScreen"
import {auth} from "./firebase";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {login, logout, selectUser} from "./features/userSlice";
import Spain from "./countries/Spain";
import Covid from './Covid.js'

function App() {
    const user = useSelector(selectUser)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
            if (userAuth){
                dispatch(login({
                    uid: userAuth.uid,
                    email: userAuth.email
                }))
            }else {
                dispatch(logout());
            }
        });

        return unsubscribe
    }, [dispatch]);



  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Router>
            {!user ? (
                <LoginScreen/>
            ):(
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/profile">
                        <ProfileScreen/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <HomeScreen/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/spain">
                        <Spain/>
                    </Route>

//////////////////// Covid part //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                    <Route path="/covid">
                        <Covid/>
                    </Route>

                </Switch>

            )}

        </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Below is the Covid.js which I created to check whether the Route works or not.

```
import React from "react";
function Covid(){
    return(
        <div className="covid">
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Covid
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

 <Link
      to={{
        pathname:
            "https://.......",}}
        target="_blank">
          <Button>...</Button>
 </Link>
```

try to put the link in a hyperlink.

```
<a 
   href="https://covid19statswebsite.netlify.app/"
   target="_blank">
      <Button>...</Button>
 </a>
```

Comment: You don't want to use `a` with `react-router` as it will cause a hard reload of the app.  You should use the `Link` component instead.